# WPF: Org Chart TreeView Conditional Formatting

Tags: wpf, xaml

The company has the traditional complex organizational structure, defining the amount of levels using the letter 'n' rather than an actual number. I will try and express the structure I'm trying to achieve in mono-spaced font:

```
         Alice
 ,--------|-------,------,------,
Bob      Fred    Jack   Kim    Lucy
 |        |      
Charlie  Greg    
Darren   Henry
Eric
```

As you can see it's not symmetrical, as Jack, Kim and Lucy report to Alice but have no reports of their own.

Using a `TreeView` with an `ItemsPanel` containing a `StackPanel` and `Orientation="Horizontal"` is [easy enough](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/CustomTreeViewLayout.aspx), but this can result in a very large `TreeView` once some people have 20 others reporting to them! You can [also use](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/AdvancedCustomTreeViewLyt.aspx) `Triggers` to peek into whether a `TreeViewItem` has children with `Property="TreeViewItem.HasItems"`, but this is not in the same context as the before-mentioned `ItemsPanel`. *Eg: I can tell that Fred has reports, but not whether they have reports of their own.*

So, can you conditionally format `TreeViewItems` to be Vertical if they have no children of their own?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did end up using tips from the linked article, which I'd already read through but didn't think would help me.

The meat of it happens here, in a converter:

```
<ValueConversion(GetType(ItemsPresenter), GetType(Orientation))> _
Public Class ItemsPanelOrientationConverter
Implements IValueConverter

Public Function Convert(ByVal value As Object, ByVal targetType As System.Type, _
ByVal parameter As Object, ByVal culture As System.Globalization.CultureInfo) _
As Object Implements System.Windows.Data.IValueConverter.Convert

    'The 'value' argument should reference an ItemsPresenter.'
    Dim itemsPresenter As ItemsPresenter = TryCast(value, ItemsPresenter)
    If itemsPresenter Is Nothing Then
        Return Binding.DoNothing
    End If

    'The ItemsPresenter''s templated parent should be a TreeViewItem.'
    Dim item As TreeViewItem = TryCast(itemsPresenter.TemplatedParent, TreeViewItem)
    If item Is Nothing Then
        Return Binding.DoNothing
    End If

    For Each i As Object In item.Items
        Dim element As StaffMember = TryCast(i, StaffMember)
        If element.IsManager Then
            'If this element has children, then return Horizontal'
            Return Orientation.Horizontal
        End If
    Next

    'Must be a stub ItemPresenter'
    Return Orientation.Vertical

End Function
```

Which in turn gets consumed in a style I created for the TreeView:

```
    <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate >
                <ItemsPanelTemplate.Resources>
                    <local:ItemsPanelOrientationConverter x:Key="conv" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate.Resources>
                <StackPanel IsItemsHost="True" 
                            Orientation="{Binding   
                            RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.TemplatedParent}, 
                            Converter={StaticResource conv}}" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
```

Answer (score 2):

Josh Smith has a excecllent CodeProject article about TreeView. Read it [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/AdvancedCustomTreeViewLyt.aspx)