# Org Chart Control/Plug-In for VB.NET WPF multitouch application

Tags: vb.net, plugins, wpf-controls, orgchart

I have been working on a UI app (written in VB.NET and using WPF) which creates charts using the Microsoft Chart Control for Windows Forms. The application retrieves data periodically from a remote database, parses and formats the data to create series, and then creates a chart based off the series which is then hosted in a WindowsFormsHost control. So far this process has been working well.

I have now been tasked with adding an organizational chart. The requirements state that it should have "drill-down" and touch functionality. I have not been able to find an org control like the chart controls I have been using. The closest one I found was the tree view control that comes with .NET Studio. I have looked at the [WPF: Org Chart TreeView Conditional Formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69928/wpf-org-chart-treeview-conditional-formatting) SO question, and also read the recommended Josh Smith CodeProject [articles](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/AdvancedCustomTreeViewLyt.aspx), but my boss does not want me to pursue developing my own org control at this time.

Is there a good third-party solution/plug-in already available? It would need:

- ...to be capable of being integrated
  into the WPF as a control (like the
  Chart Control mentioned above),
- ...to generate org charts dynamically
  by connecting to a remote Oracle
  Database to retrieve the data based
  on either predefined views or
  specific select statements (or read a
  flat file to generate an XML file
  containing all the relationships and
  branches),
- ...to have a hierarchy that was
  navigable by touch, i.e. touching a
  node would show the branches beneath
  that node--touching the node again
  would hide the branches.

Any suggestions/help are greatly appreciated. I haven't been able to find any third-party options that fit all these requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unifosys Chart4.NET is a fully-featured organization chart component:

Documentation: chart4.net

-Supports database(ODBC)/datatable/XML/CSV
-Has Expand/Collapse
-Has Drill-down and hyperlinking
-Availbale for winforms and webforms

Create Org Chart from Database:
http://unifosys.com/hierarchy-chart/Create_Organization_Chart_From_Database_Sample.html

Online Database Demo:
http://organization.unifosys.com/Create_Organization_Chart_From_Database_Sample_WebForm.aspx